# Mongoose find value in each object in array for stored document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to find refs I've stored in my db by sending an array of object to my API.
In the array I send there are 4 objects. 2 of them are already stored, 2 of them are new.

Here is what is stored in my DB:

```
[
  {
    ref: 'xxx14-010-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  },
  {
    ref: 'xxx18-050-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  },
...
]
```

My req.body look like this :

```
[
  {
    ref: 'xxx14-010-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  },
  {
    ref: 'xxx18-050-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  },
  {
    ref: 'xxx20-010-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  },
  {
    ref: 'xx324-010-S',
    colorWay: 'Black',
  }
]
```

And here is the code in my express router:

```
router.post("/api/v1/lineList", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const existingRefs = await LineList.find({ref: {$in: req.body.ref}});
    res.send(existingRefs);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

This returns an empty array where I expect to find the 2 stored objects.
How shall I proceed ?
Is there a way to get the 2 found objects and also be notified that the 2 other object where not in the db ?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT:
Here is the model:

```
const lineListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ref: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
  },
  styleName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
  },
  colorWay: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
  },
 ...
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 3600,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) syntax is:

> { field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }

So you need to pass an array like this:

```
await LineList.find({ ref: { $in: req.body.map(val => val.ref) } });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this make sens but I still get an empty array in the console.log

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: Biog Sorry I've just found my db was droped... your solution work !!!